# Operation on every pair of element in a list

Tags: python, cartesian-product

Using Python, I'd like to compare every possible pair in a list.

Suppose I have

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4]
```

I'd like to do an operation (let's call it foo) on every combination of 2 elements from the list.

The final result should be the same as

```
foo(1,1)
foo(1,2)
...
foo(4,3)
foo(4,4)
```

My first thought was to iterate twice through the list manually, but that doesn't seem very pythonic.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099987 for the case of storing the results in a new list.

Answer (score 294, accepted):

Check out [`product()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) in the `itertools` module.  It does exactly what you describe.

```
import itertools

my_list = [1,2,3,4]
for pair in itertools.product(my_list, repeat=2):
    foo(*pair)
```

This is equivalent to:

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4]
for x in my_list:
    for y in my_list:
        foo(x, y)
```

**Edit:** There are two very similar functions as well, [`permutations()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) and [`combinations()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).  To illustrate how they differ:

`product()` generates every possible pairing of elements, including all duplicates:

```
1,1  1,2  1,3  1,4
2,1  2,2  2,3  2,4
3,1  3,2  3,3  3,4
4,1  4,2  4,3  4,4
```

`permutations()` generates all unique orderings of each unique pair of elements, eliminating the `x,x` duplicates:

```
 .   1,2  1,3  1,4
2,1   .   2,3  2,4
3,1  3,2   .   3,4
4,1  4,2  4,3   .
```

Finally, `combinations()` only generates each unique pair of elements, in lexicographic order:

```
 .   1,2  1,3  1,4
 .    .   2,3  2,4
 .    .    .   3,4
 .    .    .    .
```

All three of these functions were introduced in Python 2.6.

Comment: Odd, when I run itertools.product(my_list, 2), it complains that int isn't callable. Works once I change it to: itertools.product(my_list, repeat=2)

Comment: Note that itertools.product() is new in Python 2.6.

Comment: Just for posterity, I'll point out that itertools.combinations would not generate the foo(1,1) or foo(4,4) lines in the original example.

Comment: @GuiSim — I wondered if that might be the case. In fact, for a few seconds after first posting it, my answer actually had combinations() instead of product() until I realized you had the (1, 1) and (4, 4) points listed. :-)

Comment: @orajc — Right you are! It's a named-only parameter because `product()` can take any number of iterables as arguments. I with I'd caught that sooner. :-)

Comment: Also there is combinations_with_replacement(). Like combinations(), but including the diagonal (in keeping with the illustrations).

Comment: For the lazy: To get the above results with `permutations()` and `combinations()` use `r=2` in lieu of `repeat=2` used on the example for `product()`

Comment: Is there a way to get all combinations plus all `(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)...` with itertools?

Answer (score 22):

I had a similar problem and found the solution [here](http://www.wellho.net/resources/ex.php4?item=y104/tessapy). It works without having to import any module.

Supposing a list like:

```
people = ["Lisa","Pam","Phil","John"]
```

A simplified one-line solution would look like this.

**All possible pairs**, including duplicates:

```
result = [foo(p1, p2) for p1 in people for p2 in people]
```

**All possible pairs, excluding duplicates**:

```
result = [foo(p1, p2) for p1 in people for p2 in people if p1 != p2]
```

**Unique pairs**, where order is irrelevant:

```
result = [foo(people[p1], people[p2]) for p1 in range(len(people)) for p2 in range(p1+1,len(people))]
```

---

In case you don't want to operate but just to get the pairs, removing the function `foo` and using just a tuple would be enough.

**All possible pairs**, including duplicates:

```
list_of_pairs = [(p1, p2) for p1 in people for p2 in people]
```

Result:

```
('Lisa', 'Lisa')
('Lisa', 'Pam')
('Lisa', 'Phil')
('Lisa', 'John')
('Pam', 'Lisa')
('Pam', 'Pam')
('Pam', 'Phil')
('Pam', 'John')
('Phil', 'Lisa')
('Phil', 'Pam')
('Phil', 'Phil')
('Phil', 'John')
('John', 'Lisa')
('John', 'Pam')
('John', 'Phil')
('John', 'John')
```

**All possible pairs, excluding duplicates**:

```
list_of_pairs = [(p1, p2) for p1 in people for p2 in people if p1 != p2]
```

Result:

```
('Lisa', 'Pam')
('Lisa', 'Phil')
('Lisa', 'John')
('Pam', 'Lisa')
('Pam', 'Phil')
('Pam', 'John')
('Phil', 'Lisa')
('Phil', 'Pam')
('Phil', 'John')
('John', 'Lisa')
('John', 'Pam')
('John', 'Phil')
```

**Unique pairs**, where order is irrelevant:

```
list_of_pairs = [(people[p1], people[p2]) for p1 in range(len(people)) for p2 in range(p1+1,len(people))]
```

Result:

```
('Lisa', 'Pam')
('Lisa', 'Phil')
('Lisa', 'John')
('Pam', 'Phil')
('Pam', 'John')
('Phil', 'John')
```

*Edit: After the rework to simplify this solution, I realised it is the same approach than Adam Rosenfield. I hope the larger explanation helps some to understand it better.*

Comment: I vastly prefer this to importing a library, much cleaner!

Comment: itertools is part of Python. It's not an external library.

Answer (score 4):

If you're just calling a function, you can't really do much better than:

```
for i in my_list:
    for j in my_list:
        foo(i, j)
```

If you want to collect a list of the results of calling the function, you can do:

```
[foo(i, j) for i in my_list for j in my_list]
```

which will return you a list of the result of applying `foo(i, j)` to each possible pair `(i, j)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4]

pairs=[[x,y] for x in my_list for y in my_list]
print (pairs)
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer also requires an explanation of **what** the code does and **how** it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[Ben Bank's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/942551/10720618) works well if  you want the combinations to be ordered lexicographically. However, if you want the combinations to be randomly ordered, here's a solution:

```py
import random
from math import comb


def cgen(i,n,k):
    """
    returns the i-th combination of k numbers chosen from 0,1,...,n-1
    
    forked from: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1227692
    changed from 1-indexed to 0-indexed.
    """
    # 1-index
    i += 1
    
    c = []
    r = i+0
    j = 0
    for s in range(1,k+1):
        cs = j+1
        while r-comb(n-cs,k-s)>0:
            r -= comb(n-cs,k-s)
            cs += 1
        c.append(cs-1)
        j = cs
    return c


def generate_random_combinations(n, k, shuffle=random.shuffle):
    """
    Generate combinations in random order of k numbers chosen from 0,1,...,n-1.
    
    :param shuffle: Function to in-place shuffle the indices of the combinations. Use for seeding.
    """
    total_combinations = comb(n, k)
    combination_indices = list(range(total_combinations))
    shuffle(combination_indices)
    
    for i in combination_indices:
        yield cgen(i, n, k)
```

#### Example Usage

For `N=100` and `k=4`:

```py
gen_combos = generate_random_combinations(100, 4)

for i in range(3):
    print(next(gen_combos))
```

results in:

```
[4, 9, 55, 79]
[11, 49, 58, 64]
[75, 82, 83, 91]
```

#### Use Case

For my use case, I'm implementing an algorithm that's searching for a single (or a few) combination and halts when it finds a valid combination. On average, it traverses a very small subset of all possible combinations, so there's no need to build all possible combinations up front and then shuffle (the population size is too big to fit all combinations in memory, anyway).

The randomness is crucial to finding a solution quickly because lexicographic ordering results in a single value in the population being included in all combinations until it's exhausted. For example, if we have `n=100` and `k=4`, then the results will be like:

| index | combination |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | (0, 1, 2, 3) |
| 1 | (0, 1, 2, 4) |
| 2 | (0, 1, 2, 5) |
| ... |  |
| 156848 | (0, 97, 98, 99) |
| 156849 | (1, 2, 3, 4) |

If `0` is not part of a valid solution, then we will have searched 156849 combinations for no reason. Randomizing the order helps mitigate this issue (see example output above).