# How can I get "permutations with repetitions/replacement" from a list (Cartesian product of a list with itself)?

Tags: python, combinatorics, cartesian-product

Suppose I have a list `die_faces = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`. I want to generate all 36 possible results for rolling two dice: `(1, 1)`, `(1, 2)`, `(2, 1)` etc. If I try using `permutations` from the `itertools` standard library:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> die_faces = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> list(itertools.permutations(die_faces, 2))
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 1), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 5), (4, 6), (5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 6), (6, 1), (6, 2), (6, 3), (6, 4), (6, 5)]
```

there are only 30 results, missing the ones where the same number comes up on both dice. It seems that it only generates permutations without repetitions. How can I fix this?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942543 for the case of directly calling a function with the new values.

Comment: `list1_permutations = itertools.permutations(list1, len(list2))` - example [here](https://www.adamsmith.haus/python/answers/how-to-get-all-unique-combinations-of-two-lists-in-python)

Comment: more precisely for your input `pairs = itertools.permutations(_faces, 2); print(list(pairs))`

Answer (score 219, accepted):

You are looking for the [Cartesian Product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product).

> In mathematics, a Cartesian product (or product set) is the direct product of two sets.

In your case, this would be `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}` x `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}`.
[`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) can help you there:

```
import itertools
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[p for p in itertools.product(x, repeat=2)]
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), 
 (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), 
 (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4), (4, 5), (4, 6), (5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3), 
 (5, 4), (5, 5), (5, 6), (6, 1), (6, 2), (6, 3), (6, 4), (6, 5), (6, 6)]
```

To get a random dice roll (in a **totally inefficient way**):

```
import random
random.choice([p for p in itertools.product(x, repeat=2)])
(6, 3)
```

Comment: This is an extremely inefficient way of getting 2 dice rolls…  Two calls to `random.randint` would be simpler and more efficient.

Comment: Random dice rolls will be much faster when you don't generate all possible pairs: [random.randint(1,6) for i in xrange(2)]

Comment: I wasn't actually trying to generate random rolls, just to list all possible rolls.

Answer (score 43):

You're not looking for permutations - you want the [Cartesian Product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product). For this use [product](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) from itertools:

```
from itertools import product
for roll in product([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], repeat = 2):
    print(roll)
```

Answer (score 14):

In python 2.7 and 3.1 there is a [`itertools.combinations_with_replacement`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement) function:

```
>>> list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 2))
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 2), (2, 3), (2, 4), 
 (2, 5), (2, 6), (3, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (4, 4), (4, 5), (4, 6),
 (5, 5), (5, 6), (6, 6)]
```

Comment: This solution looses out on the combinations `(2, 1)`, `(3, 2)`, `(3, 1)` and similar... In general it leaves out all combinations where the second roll is lower than the first.

Comment: Maybe not the "right" solution, but the right one for me! Thanks!

Comment: have to downvote since @holroy is right and this can be confusong

Answer (score 3):

In this case, a list comprehension is not particularly needed.

**Given**

```
import itertools as it


seq = range(1, 7)
r = 2
```

**Code**

```
list(it.product(seq, repeat=r))
```

---

**Details**

Unobviously, Cartesian product can generate subsets of permutations. However, it follows that:

- with replacement: produce all permutations n<sup>r</sup> via `product`
- without replacement: filter from the latter

*Permutations with replacement, n<sup>r</sup>*

```
[x for x in it.product(seq, repeat=r)]
```

*Permutations without replacement, n!*

```
[x for x in it.product(seq, repeat=r) if len(set(x)) == r]
```

```
# Equivalent
list(it.permutations(seq, r))
```

Consequently, all combinatoric functions could be implemented from `product`:

- [`combinations_with_replacement`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement) implemented from `product`
- [`combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) implemented from `permutations`, which can be implemented with `product` (see above)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution using only `lambdas`, `map` and `reduce`.

```
product_function = lambda n: reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, map(lambda i: list(map(lambda j: (i, j), np.arange(n))), np.arange(n)), [])
```

Essentially I'm mapping a first lambda function that given a row, iterates the columnns

```
list(map(lambda j: (i, j), np.arange(n)))
```

then this is used as the output of a new lambda function

```
lambda i:list(map(lambda j: (i, j), np.arange(n)))
```

which is mapped across all the possible rows

```
map(lambda i: list(map(lambda j: (i, j), np.arange(n))), np.arange(m))
```

and then we reduce all the resulting lists into one.

## even better

Can also use two different numbers.

```
prod= lambda n, m: reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, map(lambda i: list(map(lambda j: (i, j), np.arange(m))), np.arange(n)), [])
```

Answer (score -2):

First, you'll want to turn the generator returned by itertools.permutations(list) into a list first. Then secondly, you can use set() to remove duplicates
Something like below:

```
def permutate(a_list):
    import itertools
    return set(list(itertools.permutations(a_list)))
```

Comment: That does not include duplicates.

Comment: OP explicitly wants duplicates