# Save itertools product loop value and then resume from the last result

Tags: python, cryptography, python-itertools, brute-force

I'm using this code to break an simple password *mycubana*, but I want to "pause" the itertools loop so that, after some time, I could resume the loop starting from the last saved `itertools.product` value. Is there any way to do it without change a lot of the code  ?

Code:

```
import string
from itertools import chain, product

def bruteforce(charset, minlenght, maxlenght):
    return(''.join(candidate) 
          for candidate in chain.from_iterable(product(charset, repeat = i)
          for i in range(minlenght, maxlenght)))

contador = 0
for attempt in bruteforce(string.ascii_lowercase, 8, 9):
    codigo = 'mycubana'
    contador+=1
    if attempt==codigo:
        print(attempt)
        contador=0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's actually pretty simple. Using your environment and the definition of `bruteforce`, the following code will perform two runs of 10 candidates each on the generated sequence:

```
bf26_8 = bruteforce(string.ascii_lowercase, 8, 9)

count = 0

for c in bf26_8:
    count += 1
    print(c)
    if count == 10:
        break

print("======== PAUSED ========")

for c in bf26_8:
    count += 1
    print(c)
    if count == 20:
        break
```

The "trick" is to store the result of `bruteforce` in a variable. That result is a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators), so if you iterate on it, but do not exhaust it (i.e., break the iteration loop), it will give you the continuations values once you start iterating again.

Comment: But I would like to iterate a list of 26 characters up to length 10 and it will  die out of memory before it completes, like this one post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747254/python-brute-force-algorithm

Comment: I edited the answer to show you that no explosion will happen. Generators (I added a link in the answer) do not create the entire result sequence upfront, but are a objects enabling the **serial** generation of a sequence, by maintaining the code to generated it and some context (e.g., program instruction pointer and values of local variables).