# Permutation of x length of 2 characters

Tags: python, python-2.7

Lets say I have two characters: `a` & `b`. I want to get a list of all possible [permutations](http://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations.html) of `a` and `b` for a given length (i.e. `5`), using Python 2.7.

I have looked at [itertools.permutations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations), but was unable to find a way that allowed me to use 2 characters to build a permutation longer than 2 characters.

I have also looked at multiple SO answers for Python permutations, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/104436/6181088), but this, along with the others, will only give permutations of `len(input)` length.

Also, if there is a good way to do this using a different programming language, please suggest it. I am not set in stone on using Python for this.

Comment: You need permutations with repetitions, have you seen that answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099987/generating-permutations-with-repetitions-in-python

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That way:

```
import itertools
x = ['a','b']
print [p for p in itertools.product(x, repeat=5)]
```