# How to produce permutations with replacement in Python

Tags: python, numpy, python-2.7, python-itertools

I am trying to write some code (as part of a larger script) to develop numpy arrays of length *n*, which I can use to change the sign of an input list of length *n*, in all possible ways. 
I am trying to produce all possible permutations of 1 and -1 of length *n*.

If I use `itertools.permutations`, it will not accept a repeat length greater than 2, because of not allowing repetitions. If I use `itertools.combinations_with_replacement`, then not all of the permutations are produced. I need "permutations_with_replacement". 
I tried to use `itertools.product`, but I cannot get it to work.

Here is my code so far (n is an unknown number, depending on the length of the input list).

```
import numpy as np
import itertools

ones = [-1, 1]
multiplier = np.array([x for x in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(ones, n)])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get "permutations with repetitions/replacement" from a list (Cartesian product of a list with itself)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099987/how-can-i-get-permutations-with-repetitions-replacement-from-a-list-cartesian)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you want?

```
>>> import itertools
>>> choices = [-1, 1]
>>> n = 3
>>> l = [choices] * n
>>> l
[[-1, 1], [-1, 1], [-1, 1]]
>>> list(itertools.product(*l))
[(-1, -1, -1), (-1, -1, 1), (-1, 1, -1), (-1, 1, 1), (1, -1, -1), (1, -1, 1), (1, 1, -1), (1, 1, 1)]
```

Comment: Rather than build the `l` list of lists, use the `repeat` argument to `itertools.product` (available since 2.6): `list(itertools.product(choices, repeat=3))`.