# How to use itertools.combinations_with_replacement by avoiding particular type of combination

Tags: python, python-itertools

How can I use

> itertools.combinations_with_replacement

by leaving out some particular type of combinations. In the case

> list(combinations_with_replacement([1, 2, 3, 4], 3))

I need to avoid (1,1,1), (2,2,2), (3,3,3), (4,4,4) by leaving all the rest.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099987/generating-permutations-with-repetitions) is a good reference, but I could not find what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You may combine [`itertools.combinations_with_replacement()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement) with a simple [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) function:

```
combinations = combinations_with_replacement([1, 2, 3, 4], 3)
filtered = filter(lambda c: len(set(c)) > 1, combinations)
```

You are in charge of selecting which combinations should be filtered or not. Here using a lambda function: if all elements are the same, discard it.

Comment: It works and gave exactly what I needed, THNK YOU !!
But I have no idea how it works, where I can read bout this filter?

Comment: @kalinfirst You may look at the documentation page I linked. Basically, `filter()` needs two arguments. The first one is a function which return `True` if the element is accepted, `False` if it should be discarded. The second argument is the list of element on which the filtering function should be applied.

Comment: In fact my question should be why "len(set(c)) > 1" remove the triple combinations

Comment: @kalinfirst Oh sorry. So, for example if `c == (1, 2, 3)` then `set(c) == {1, 2, 3}` and `len(set(c)) == 3`, so this combination if accepted. However, if `c == (1, 1, 1)` then `set(c) == {1}` so it is discarded. Sets are non-ordered data structures which stores elements different from each others. Once the combination `(1, 1, 1)` is transformed to a set `{1}`, it's easy to see if all elements of the combination were the same.

Answer (score 1):

If the input list is sorted or contains distinct elements, this would also yield the intended result:

```
combinations = combinations_with_replacement([1, 2, 3, 4], 3)
filtered = (c for c in combinations if c[0] != c[-1])  # Use square brackets if a list is needed
```

The solution works because in each generated combination tuple, elements are sorted according to their indices in the input list. Therefore if `c[0] == c[-1]`, then for any element `e` such that `index(c[0])<=index(e)<=index(c[-1])`, `c[0]==e==c[-1]` holds according to the constraint of the input.

Comment: Thank you. This also works. And also I don't know why :-(

Comment: I have added an explanation.