# Permutations with repetitions?

Tags: python, repeat, python-itertools, permute

I can do this with itertools :

```
list(permutations([1,2,3],2))
: [(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2)]
```

but how do I also generate :

```
 (1,1),(2,2),(3,3)
```

of course w/o doing it separately : [(i,i) for i in range(4)]

Comment: What about `product([1,2,3], repeat=2)` using itertools as well?

Comment: ooo.. i see ..i tried product([1,2,3], 2)  ;)

Comment: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Answer (score 3):

Adding to Nakor's comment, it looks like what you want is the [cartesian product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product). You can get that with `list(itertools.product([1,2,3],repeat=2))`.

[Permutations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) on the other hand, according to the documentation

> The code for permutations() can be also expressed as a subsequence of product(), filtered to exclude entries with repeated elements (those from the same position in the input pool)

so it looks like there is no way to use `list(itertools.permutations([1,2,3],2))` and get the output that you want without using additional logic.

Comment: @sten: Is this what you wanted?

Comment: this is the one : product([1,2,3], repeat=2)

Answer (score 1):

You are seeking a [`permutations_with_replacement`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_with_repetition) tool.

That will give [n**r results](https://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations.html), e.g. 3**2 = 9 total results.

Python does not yet implement this tool; reasons unclear.  However, *permutations* can generally be implemented with a *Cartesian product*.

**Code**

Modified from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations):

```
def permutations_with_replacement(iter_, r=None):
    """Yield all or some permutations from a replenished pool; from docs."""
    pool = tuple(iter_)
    n = len(pool)
    r = n if r is None else r

    for indices in itertools.product(range(n), repeat=r):
        #if len(set(indices)) == r:
            #print(indices)

        yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
```

**Demo**

```
results = list(permutations_with_replacement([1, 2, 3], r=2))
len(results)
# 9
```

```
results
# [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]
```

Equivalently reduced to:

```
list(itertools.product([1, 2, 3], repeat=2))
# [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]
```

See also more answers to this question from an [earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099987/generating-permutations-with-repetitions).

Answer (score 0):

Nakor got the right answer :

```
  product([1,2,3], repeat=2)
```

I made mistake to try :

```
 list(product([1,2,3],2))
```

which errors :

```
  TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```