# python combination with replacement not working as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, combinations, combinatorics

I would like to produce all combinations of certain length by using a set of allowed characters with replacement:

I thought  `itertools.combinations_with_replacement` is what I need. So this is what I did:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
allowed = ['0', '1', '8', '6', '9']
comb = list(combinations_with_replacement(allowed,2))
```

Yet the number of combinations thus produced is 15. But it should be 25 (5^2). What is going on?

EDIT:

I replaced `combinations_with_replacement` with `permutations` as suggested by @Michael Bianconi but it did not work either - I get a result set of 20, not 25.

Comment: Combination vs permutation?

Comment: Combinations, not permutations as ordering is irrelevant.

Comment: Okay, because there are 15 combinations but 25 permutations.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get "permutations with repetitions/replacement" from a list (Cartesian product of a list with itself)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099987/how-can-i-get-permutations-with-repetitions-replacement-from-a-list-cartesian)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably search for the product:

```
import itertools
allowed = ['0', '1', '8', '6', '9']
product = list(itertools.product(allowed, repeat=2))
print(len(product))
```

> 25

Strings are iterable in Python, so you can use:

```py
import itertools
for result in itertools.product('01869', repeat=2)):
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
00, 01, 08, 06, 09
11, 18, 16, 19
88, 86, 89
66, 69
99
```

There are 15 possible combinations.

Comment: When it comes to combinations, where order doesn't matter, 96 is the same as 69.