# Python permutations with repetitions

Tags: python, combinations, permutation, python-itertools

If I use "itertools.permutations", I don't get all possible combinations. (i.e. "abb" or "cbc")

```
import itertools
charList = ["a", "b", "c"]

per = itertools.permutations(charList, 3)

for val in per:
    print(val)
```

I'm searching for something like "itertools.product", but it works only for numbers.

Comment: *I'm searching for something like "itertools.product", but it works only for numbers.* - that's simply not true...

Comment: @mousetail same problem

Comment: `list(it.product(charList, repeat=3))` do the job

Comment: @Tomerikoo Can you help me, for my situation it is not working.

Comment: @DavidS I tried, but it is still not working.

Comment: So [edit] the question with a [mre]. Part of that is what you tried, what you got, and how is that different from what you expect

Comment: If you want strings instead of tuples of characters, you'll need `list(map(''.join, product(charList, repeat=3)))` instead.

Comment: repetition allowed or not?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating permutations with repetitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099987/generating-permutations-with-repetitions)

Comment: @Ajay this is what I need abb and bba etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import itertools
x = ['a', 'b', 'c']
print([''.join(p) for p in itertools.product(x, repeat=3)])
```

Will produce:

```bash
['aaa', 'aab', 'aac', 'aba', 'abb', 'abc', 'aca', 'acb', 'acc', 'baa', 'bab', 'bac', 'bba', 'bbb', 'bbc', 'bca', 'bcb', 'bcc', 'caa', 'cab', 'cac', 'cba', 'cbb', 'cbc', 'cca', 'ccb', 'ccc']
```