# How do I print all combinations of this list?

Tags: python

This is the list given but can be any number of integers

```
list = [2,3,5,6]
```

This should be the outcome:

```
(2,2)
(2,3)
(2,5)
(2,6)
(3,2)
(3,3)
(3,5)
(3,6)
(5,2)
(5,3)
(5,5)
(5,6)
(6,2)
(6,3)
(6,5)
(6,6)
```

Comment: have a look at `itertools`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Operation on every pair of element in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942543/operation-on-every-pair-of-element-in-a-list)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

```
list(itertools.product(l, repeat=2))
[(2, 2),
 (2, 3),
 (2, 5),
 (2, 6),
 (3, 2),
 (3, 3),
 (3, 5),
 (3, 6),
 (5, 2),
 (5, 3),
 (5, 5),
 (5, 6),
 (6, 2),
 (6, 3),
 (6, 5),
 (6, 6)]
```

Comment: firstly, you shouln't give answers to such low quality questions because it encourages more of them. secondly, it would be better to use `itertools.product`

Comment: Where's `(3,2)`, `(5,2)`, etc...? Combinations is not what the OP wants based on their desired outcome.

Answer (score 1):

The solution could be:

```
[(i,j) for i in list for j in list]
```

which is the "list-comprehension" version of:

```
result = []
for i in list:
   for j in list:
       result.append((i,j))
```

Please note that using `list = something` you are overriding a python keyword.